# Linux: top -bn1 shows always CPU 0%

Tags: linux, bash, cpu, cpu-usage

Following top-table is given:

[image]

With following command:

```
top -bn1p 20101
```

I get following result:

```
top - 11:38:34 up 248 days,  1:17,  3 users,  load average: 0,09, 0,16, 0,18
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,8 us,  0,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 97,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:  24693872 total, 24430392 used,   263480 free,   142532 buffers
KiB Swap: 15625212 total,    17508 used, 15607704 free. 12526360 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
20101 root      20   0 11,636g 262944  18260 S   0,0  1,1  88:13.84 java
```

Like you see CPU-Value is 0.0 . Why? It should be 0.3.
Is this a bug?

Comment: What, why should it?

Comment: It's the real-time CPU usage, which keeps changing.

Comment: You are measuring performance in a single snap shot in time and expecting this snap shot to be consistent over time. This is rarely the case and I would suggest monitoring the process over an extended period of time

Comment: If you run `top -bn1` multiple times, you can see it changing.

Comment: if I run top -bn1 multiple times, the values does NOT changed